# confused with the date format in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a table in MySQL, and load the data into it which i have as a txt file 
the date format in the txt file is `dd/mm/yyyy` with few dates as 12/12/1988 and few as 1/2/1988 
really confused how to give value for the date column while creating the table ?

Please help, I am a beginner with MySQL.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Comment: In the future, you might get better answers if you try something yourself first (like reading the manual as suggested by Bitendian).

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Supports Dates in Format `'YYYY-MM-DD'` i.e `'2014-01-28'`

You can load the date strings into user-defined variables, and then use a function to convert them to MySQL dates.

**Example**

I have a table Like below

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
patentId INT,
USPatentNum INT,
title CHAR(10),
grantDate DATE,
filedDate DATE
);
```

Now I need to load string dates into DATE column we can do like

```
load data local infile  '/home/abdul/Test.csv'
into table TestTable
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
ignore 1 lines
(  patentId,  USPatentNum,  title,  @grantDate,  @filedDate)
set grantDate = STR_TO_DATE(@grantDate, '%m/%d/%Y'),
filedDate = STR_TO_DATE(@filedDate, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: @joey, if that worked for you accept this answer to give the writer the proper reputation.